# convert date yyyymmdd to yyJJJ or Julian Date

Tags: c#, excel

Need a formula in excel and c# to convert data in "yyyymmdd" format to julian date format "yyJJJ"?  Where "JJJ" is the Julian date of day submitted.  Is JJJ a number from 1 to 365 or 999 or 366?  I don't think its 366, but we do have leap year so it could be leap year.

In Excel I'm trying to use the following:

```
 =Year() & DAYS360("20110101","20110930")
```

In C# I'm using now() to get the current date.   But I'm want the number of days between Jan 1st, and current date.  Not sure if this is the correct prototype formula:

```
Prepend Two digit year format to the following
    Number of Days between "20110101" and "20110930" in "YY" format
```

Comment: In .NET, `DateTime.DayOfYear` works quite well. For Excel, see http://www.cpearson.com/excel/jdates.htm

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of handling this yourself in C#, you could simply use the [JulianCalendar class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.juliancalendar%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

And to get today in the Julian calendar, you could do:

```
JulianCalendar calendar = new JulianCalendar();
var today=DateTime.Today;
var dateInJulian = calendar.ToDateTime(today.Year, today.Month, today.Day, today.Hour, today.Minute, today.Second, today.Millisecond);
```

EDIT:

And I realized I didn't help you with a good way to get a result in the YYJJJ format you were looking for, it's quite simple:

```
var stringResult=string.Format("{0}{1}", dateInJulian.ToString("yy"), dateInJulian.DayOfYear);
```

Sadly, I don't think there's an equivalent of `dateTime.ToString("JJJ");` that will give the day of the year, hence my little `string.Format()` work-around, but it works just as well!

EDIT2:

So Phoog educated me a bit below in the comments, and pointed out that you weren't looking for today in the Julian Calendar, which is what the above code would give in respect to the JulianCalendar class. Rather, it appears you're looking for the Ordinal date (this piece added for future reader clarification). I'm going to leave the above so that someone doesn't make the same mistake that I did. What you really want, I believe, is the code from the first edit but without the JulianCalendar business, so:

```
var dateToConvert = DateTime.Today // Or any other date you want!
var stringResult=string.Format("{0}{1}", dateToConvert.ToString("yy"), dateToConvert.DayOfYear);
```

Comment: Such a simple answer, but such a truth too! ;-)

Comment: -1.  This isn't at all what the OP is looking for, and in fact, it's incorrect.  For 2011-09-30, the dateInJulian variable in the example will have a value of 2011-10-13.  But the correct result, given the poster's requirements, is 11273 (since 273 is the `DayOfYear` for 2011-09-30).

Comment: @phoog Sorry, I'm pretty sure you don't know what you're talking about. 273 is the day of the Gregorian Calendar year, and the day of the Julian Calendar year is in fact 286. It's possible that what the OP was looking for was the Julian day, in which case you're right and the above is incorrect but his question says Julian date which implies calendar to me. Reading the question again, perhaps you're right and that's what he's looking for, even so the code isn't incorrect and can easily be used to find what you're talking about, if you substitute `today` for `dateInJulian`.

Comment: @kevek, I definitely know the difference between the Julian and Gregorian calendars, which is why I surmised that the OP wasn't really talking about Julian dates in his question.  I wasn't saying that your code is incorrect, but that your answer would not give the correct result for the OP's requirements.  If you edit your answer, I'll remove my downvote.

Comment: @Kevek, by the way, today's ordinal in the Julian Calendar may be 286, because that's because today's date in the Julian Calendar is 13 Oct.  The ordinal number for Julian Sept 30th 2011 is also 273, because it's the 273d day of the Julian year.

Comment: @Phoog I did a little reading and a little understanding and I follow what you're saying a little better now. (Going to continue to double check that I really do understand). Feel free to leave the downvote if you wish as I was a little snippy and it was undeserved. I shouldn't post when I'm annoyed at outside events! My apologies, and thank you for your explanations.

Comment: No problem about being snippy -- I'm fairly thick-skinned, at least online :)  Anyway changed my downvote to an upvote.  I was only concerned that the OP would accept your answer and get incorrect results.  Now that the answer is more detailed and more informative, this is unlikely.  Plus I like the fact that you left the original answer to help others understand the issues at hand.

Answer (score 6):

According to these articles, you should be using the term "Ordinal date" rather than "Julian date":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_date

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day

According to the first, the ISO standard for ordinal date specifies a 4-digit year, and that the range is from 1 to 366, so January 1st is 1.

This of course means that dates between March and December will have two possible values depending on whether the date falls in a leap year.

Bala's solution (with the `+ 1` option given in the comments) will therefore suffice.

EDIT: The `DateTime` type's own DayOfYear property, as Jim Mischel pointed out, is simpler and probably faster.

Comment: I have to use two digit year format b/c its part of the state specification.

Comment: Fair enough.  I would then check with the source of the specification to see whether they prefer to use `1` or `0` for the first of January.  If that's not possible or adviseable, I'd use `1`.

Answer (score 2):

in c# you can do

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
DateTime firstJan = new DateTime(dt.Year, 1, 1);

int daysSinceFirstJan = (dt - firstJan).Days + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Bala.  Quick question: Is 01/01/2011 JJJ = 001, or 000?  And is 09/30/2011 JJJ = 269 or 270? thx

Comment: @RetroCoder I don't know julian calendar. Right now the above snippet will return 0 for jan 1st. if it has to be on, just do `(dt - firstJan).Days + 1;`

Comment: I loved this logic and used that myself !

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are looking for is this:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
string ordinalDate = dt.ToString("yy") + dt.DayOfYear.ToString("000");
```

This will give you a string that is always 5 digits with a two digit year and 3 digit day of the year.
Keveks answer will give you a string that could be 3, 4, or 5 digits.